# Como comparar dois campos de valores idênticos porem tamanho diferentes?

Tags: sql, oracle, pl-sql

Tenho uma base de dados no qual possui campos com o mesmo nome porem com tamanho diferentes

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

preciso escolher o campo com o VARCHAR maior.
Como posso fazer isso ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Calculo se que querias fazer um *SELECT*, então é só por no *SELECT* em letras grandes:

```
SELECT CNES FROM Table
```

Ou por exemplo se queres selecionar os dois só:

```
SELECT cnes,CNES FROM Table
```

Mas acho que por razões como esta seria melhor mudares o nome da coluna para algo mais fácil de distinguir.

**EDIT**: Não notei que era uma pergunta sobre o SQL do Oracle, mas calculo que seja igual. Corrigem-me se estiver errado! :)